# Allow filtering function in Cassandra (which choice is correct?)

Tags: cassandra, time-series, cassandra-3.0

I am currently trying to model some time series data in base of Cassandra. 
For example i have a table bigint_table, which was created by following query

**

> CREATE TABLE bigint_table (name_id int,tuuid timeuuid, timestamp
>   timestamp, value text,  PRIMARY KEY ((name_id),tuuid, timestamp)) WITH
>   CLUSTERING ORDER BY (tuuid asc, timestamp asc)

**
**tuuid** column was added because without it I had problems and I lost some data while inserting them in DB. **name_id** represents the channel's ID data comes from.tuuid column was added because without it I had problems and I lost some data while inserting them in DB. In one table there are lots of data with the same ID, but they are unique by **timestamp** and **tuuid** (**values** also can be the same sometimes).
I consistently execute 2 different queries to get values and timestamps

1. > select value from bigint_table where name_id=6 and   timestamp>'
   >   2017-11-01  8:26:47.970+0000' and   timestamp<'2017-11-30 
   >   8:26:52.048+0000' order by tuuid asc, timestamp asc allow filtering

2.

> select timestamp from bigint_table where name_id=6 and   timestamp>'
>   2017-11-01  8:26:47.970+0000' and   timestamp<'2017-11-30 
>   8:26:52.048+0000' order by tuuid asc, timestamp asc allow filtering

[In this post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) author says one need to resist the urge to just add ALLOW FILTERING to itand one should think about  data, model and what one is trying to do.

I thought a lot about using **ALLOW FILTERING** function or not, and I figured out that I have no choice in my case and I need to use it. But those words in post I mentioned above are keeping me in doubt. I would like to know your advise and what do you  thnik about my problem. Is there  another way to model  my data tables, queries of which do not require **ALLOW FILTERING**? I would be very very thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you need allow filtering is because you have the clustering column (tuuid, timestamp)in the wrong order. In this case the data stored first by tuuid and then by timestamp.But you're actually choosing data by timestamp and then ordering by tuuid so Cassandra can't use the indexes that you have specified. The order when you define the primary key matters.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you mean if i change clustering column and write (timestamp, timeuuid), after that call by the same query,  I won't need allow filtering?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Since you don't use your clustering columns in the right order Cassandra has to sort them every time you do the query, hence the allow filtering. You can find more information here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompoundPrimaryKeyConcept.html

Comment: Simon, actually i was losing data due to Timestamp precision of Cassandra. Cassandra can distinguish timestamp by milliseconds, not more. In my case sometimes I need to insert data faster, so I was losing some data when first clustering column was timestamp. Due to that I added the timeuuid in order to avoid losing data.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Would it make sense for you to remove timestamp column and use timeuuid functions instead? http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

Comment: I know about ToTimestamp function, but sometimes I need to insert data points in the past date, so anyway I need to use timestamp.
Thank you alot Simon :)